# nginx Rewrite for CImage Cache

Tags: nginx, rewrite, cache

I'm setting up a script (http://dbwebb.se/opensource/cimage) to do some image processing and I'd like to cache the resulting image output.  I have that part working fine.

The problem I'm running into is when someone goes to download the image from the cache.  The question mark on the query string is passed through on the proxy url, so the downloaded image has a default filename of "test.jpg&height=200" which doesn't open properly on windows without renaming it.

I need to set up some kind of rewrite rule so that the first "?" character gets changed to a "&".  It would also need to still work if the request is simply just for the filename without any additional parameters.

What do I need to add to make the url accessible with a "?", but send to the server as an "&"?

**Origin**

http://origin.example.com/img.php?src=folder1/test.jpg&height=200

**Current Edge Cache (this is how it works now):**

http://cdn.example.com/dynimg/folder1/test.jpg&height=200

**Desired Edge Cache:**

http://cdn.example.com/dynimg/folder1/test.jpg?height=200
http://cdn.example.com/dynimg/folder1/test.jpg

**nginx config (the important area):**

```
location /dynimg/ {

                expires                 14d;

                proxy_pass              http://origin.example.com/img.php?src=;
                proxy_cache_valid       200 302 2880m;
                proxy_cache_valid       404 1m;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image processing application should send the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header, where the desired filename is sent. This way the user's browser will use that filename instead of the filename derived from the URL of the request.

Nginx proxy cache will save the `Content-Disposition` header, and then users will get the correct filenames.